# Comparison to 0.0 with floating point values

Tags: c++, floating-point, double, equality

When using floating point numbers, there can sometimes be rounding issues. Because of this, it is usually not recommended to compare the result of calculations with == or != and instead to use an appropriate bound like `abs(a-b)<1.0e-10`.

But would it be appropriate to use it to compare to `0.0`?

Here is what I am talking about:

```
double foo(){
    //code which can return values that aren't 0.0
    //all returns are either literals or global variables defined with literals
    return 0.0;
}
```

Here `f` will always return either exactly `0.0` or a number that is unambiguously not `0.0`. Specifically, the numbers will all have magnitudes greater than `0.1` but less than `2.0`.

Will `0.0==foo()` always be `true` if it returns `0.0`? Is it possible for `0.0==foo()` to be `true` if `foo` returns a value other than `0.0`?

Comment: *"Will 0.0==foo() always be true if it returns 0.0?"* Yes.

Comment: But of course you have to be sure that it returns 0.0 unambiguously, and the only really reliable  way to have it do that is to return the 0.0 literal, not the result of a calculation.

Comment: Mandatory reading: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Watch out for `-0.0` and other wild beasts.

Comment: @Neil: float(2) / float(2) - 1.0f will work perfectly (where 2 is an integral type)

Comment: I would use `std::optional` or `boost::optional`. It would make intention clear and remove doubts.

Comment: @lorro It seems unlikely he wants to perform that specific calculation. If he did, he could simply use 0.0. My comment was about real-world calculations in general, though perhaps I didn't make that obvious.

Comment: Also - some consider this an anti-pattern - you might always have a single global const floatZero = 0.0; . This has the advantage that it can be returned by const ref in lookups and when done so, address can also be compared. So you know e.g. if the element was in your map, while you still have an acceptable default behavior.

Comment: @NeilButterworth what I meant, for sensible-sized int i and j, if you know that i%j == 0 and you receive these converted to float, it's safe to do i/j (and a bunch of other stuff, like *). Basically you can use float as a specific-sized signed int, with the exception that / is ok only as above and % is N/A. Granted, float(i) * float(j) would've been a better example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly correct in your case to use floating point equality `== 0.0`.

It perfectly fits the intention of the function (return some value or 0.0 if it fails). Using any other epsilon is somehow arbitrary and require the knowledge of the range of correct values. If ever something went to change that could well be the range of values rather than 0, so testing `== 0.0` is not less future proof than other solutions IMO.

The only problem I see is that some compilers will warn about suspiscious usage of equality (-Wfloat-equal)... That's as usefull as warning about `int a,b,c; ...; c=a+b;` because such instruction might possibly lead to problem (integer overflow and undefined behaviour). Curiously, I never saw the second warning.

So if you want to make usage of -Wall -Werror compiler options future proof, you might encode failure differently (with a negative value for example) and test for foo < 0.0 - until someone discover that floating point inequality might require a tolerance too and declare the construct as suspiscious.

Answer (score 1):

Up to `std::numeric_limits::digits<float>` you're safe. This is because the mantissa is integral type (usually platform-specific uint; which is then extended to a float by sign bit and exponent).

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/digits

Answer (score 0):

If you return a literal `0.0` then yes, but it is generally not a good idea, because while that is true today, can you be sure that under maintenance or code reuse it will remain true.  Better to code something that will work in a wider set of circumstances.  In this case:

```
foo() < 0.1
```

will return false for all values you have specified.  A more general solution is to test for sufficient proximity to zero:

```
static const EPSILON = 0.00001 ;
std::fabs( foo() - 0.0 ) < EPSILON ;
```

It is better to use one of the above patterns, because it does not require `foo()` to make any guarantees about the precision of "zero".

Comment: Note that OP wrote exactly the same (i.e., wanted to avoid the second).

Comment: @lorro : I am not sure he wanted to avoid it; he's just asking whether his alternative is _appropriate_.  My point is that comparing literal 0.0 works in a limited set of circumstances that may not hold over time (code changes and is reused, or colleagues copy your code in circumstances where it is unsafe), so it is best to avoid.

Comment: Apart from -0.0, % and /, it works basically as am int with a given mantissa, so it's safe and valid in some cases. Actually, some mainframes use float as the underlying type of int with exponent of 1 if I remember correctly.

Comment: first paragraph, last sentence & next one makes me think so. (& yes, technically the answer is correct - I'm just saying that in the OP's use case - and generalized one - it's safe).

Comment: I am not arguing that it is not safe in the example given.  If `foo()` is later modified you have to remember that you made such assumptions and maintain them or break the code.  A calculated value may have precision errors that make it near but not precisely zero.

Comment: I beg to differ; you say he wants to avoid it, I am reading it as asking whether it is appropriate to avoid it.  Subtle difference.